# WPF text Wrap vs WrapWithOverflow

Tags: wpf, word-wrap

What's the "conceptual" difference between `TextWrapping="Wrap"` and `TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"` (e.g. for a TextBox)?
In the MSDN page about the class TextBox there is nothing ...
Thank you.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping.aspx)

> **WrapWithOverflow**    Line-breaking occurs if the line overflows beyond
> the available block width. However, a line may overflow beyond the
> block width if the line breaking algorithm cannot determine a line
> break opportunity, as in the case of a very long word constrained in a
> fixed-width container with no scrolling allowed.
> **NoWrap**  No line
> wrapping is performed.
> **Wrap**    Line-breaking occurs if the line
> overflows beyond the available block width, even if the standard line
> breaking algorithm cannot determine any line break opportunity, as in
> the case of a very long word constrained in a fixed-width container
> with no scrolling allowed.

Comment: I know this question was directed at WPF, but I thought it might be worth noting that `WrapWithOverflow` is not supported in Silverlight. Only `Wrap` and `NoWrap` are supported in Silverlight. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I read this and am still not certain of the difference. Is the basic idea that `WrapWithOverFlow` will not break words, but `Wrap` will?

Comment: @BrianJ - See my answer for some examples.

Answer (score 372):

Some examples:

This is the original, unwrapped version:

[image: No wrapping]

---

This is `NoWrap`.

[image: NoWrap]

---

This is `Wrap`. The words `Remove` and `Sample` have been wrapped at the `ve` and `le`, respectively, even though there is no line break opportunity.

[image: Wrap]

---

This is `WrapWithOverflow`. The `ve` and `le` are not visible (they overflow the available block width) because there is no line break opportunity. The `All`, in both cases, has been wrapped because the `space` character is a line break opportunity.

[image: WrapWithOverflow]

---

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, here's some examples of how `Wrap` treats spaces. When `Width` is `100`, `Wrap` and `WrapWithOverflow` are identical. `Wrap` treats the space between `wider` and `example` as a line-break opportunity, so `example` is put on a new line to preserve the entire, continuous word.

[image]

Comment: This answer would benefit from including one more (wider) button example in each mode that does have a valid whitespace break.  At a glance, it implies that `Wrap` completely ignores whitespace breaks, but that isn't true.

Answer (score 18):

One thing to add to the other answers, WrapWithOverflow lets you use text trimming (ellipsis) on the long words that get cut off:

[image]

```xml
<TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="120" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
    A really long word is antidisestablishmentarianism and we can use ellipsis trimming.
</TextBlock>
```